# Associative arrays in LotusScript

Tags: lotusscript, lotus

Is there any way to implement associative array in LotusScript?
If yes, post a little demo code please.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Associative arrays are called Lists in LotusScript.  [Here's](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FLSAZ_WORKING_WITH_LISTS.html) the IBM page on lists in LotusScript.

Sample from that page:

```
' Declare a list to hold employee IDs.
' The list tags will be the names of the employees.
Dim empList List As Double
' Make absolutely sure empList is Double.
If TypeName(empList) <> "DOUBLE LIST" Then
  Print "Warning: empList is " & TypeName(empList)
End If
If DataType(empList) <> 2053 Then
  Print "Warning: empList is " & CStr(DataType(empList))
  ' We expected 2053 (that is, 2048 + 5).
End If
' Declare a String variable for user name.
Dim ans As String
' Declare a Double variable for user ID.
Dim yourID As Double
' Declare an Integer variable to serve as a flag.
Dim found As Boolean
' Create some list elements and assign them values.
empList("Maria Jones") = 12345
empList("Roman Minsky") = 23456
empList("Joe Smith") = 34567
empList("Sal Piccio") = 91234
' Ask the user to enter the name to be removed from the
' list of employees who have been assigned parking spaces.
ans$ = InputBox$("Which employee no longer needs a space?")
' Check to see if the employee's name appears as a list tag
' in the list. If not, display a message and stop. Otherwise,
' validate the employee's ID. If everything checks out,
' remove the employee item from the parking list. 
If IsElement(empList(ans$)) = True then
    Print ans$ & "  is a valid employee name."
    yourID# = CDbl(InputBox$("What's " & ans$ & "'s ID?"))
    ' The following ForAll block does two things:
    ' it checks to see if yourID# is a valid ID and,
    ' if so, if it matches the ID for the employee
    ' whose name is ans$. If so, that element is removed
    ' (erased) from the list. The found flag is initially
    ' FALSE (0). If yourID# is a valid ID, found is set to
    ' TRUE (-1). The variable empID is the reference variable
    ' in the ForAll loop.
    found = FALSE
    ForAll empID In empList
        If empID = yourID# then
           found = TRUE
           If ListTag(empID) = ans$ then
              Erase empList(ans$)
              ' Verify the removal of the list element.
              If  IsElement(empList(ans$)) = FALSE then
                Print ans$ & " is no longer on the list."
             End If
           Else
              Print "Valid ID but wrong employee."
           End If
           ' No need to look further for yourID#,
           ' so get out of the ForAll loop.
           Exit ForAll
        End If
     End ForAll
     If found = False then
        Print "No such employee ID."
     End If
Else
   Print "No such employee."
End if
```

Comment: Here is a blog entry about lists I wrote a while back: 
http://blog.texasswede.com/sntt-lists-the-forgotten-gem-in-lotusscript/
And here is an example of how you can improve performance substantially by using lists: http://blog.texasswede.com/using-lotusscript-lists-to-increase-performance/